Leaflet.js dragging is really slow in Firefox
I've made a Leaflet map for my clients using Django. The map is working great on Chromium based browsers (I've tried Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge and DuckDuckGo), but dragging around is insanely slow on Firefox.
The dragging gets better if I use an smaller window and gets worse on fullscreen.
My map is loading some WMS layers, that I host on GeoServer from PostGIS.
So far I've tried:

Disabling the WMS layers and dragging gets better. Obviously that's not an option nor a fix.

Changing all the layers from their native projection (EPSG:25830) to EPSG:4326 and uploading then again to GeoServer. Performance is the same.


